# Is it ok to create a community-wiki based on several different answers?

Tags: discussion, self-answer, community-wiki

Can I create a community-wiki about a problems I faced and ***how*** I solved it, in a sort of **"First check this... then that..."**?

I have seen **a lot** of people with similar problems as mine, so maybe we can create an actual *community wiki* for future reference as to that kind of problem, since it is something that's happens with some frequency.

Is it wrong to create that kind of post, putting together the information from many different answers related to the same kind of technology/equipment/configuration/etc; so future users can have all the necessary information centralized in one place?

Comment: Do you mean "Can I create a question and answer it myself?" if so then [yes, you can!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: You mean a self-answered question? There are no actual _threads_ in SO...

Comment: If you found the answer in earlier SO posts, then why do you see the need to re-post that same information in another question?  If you feel that you can provide useful additional information to those past questions, either by including more information than those earlier answers, or explaining them better, then why do you feel the need to post a new question?  If you think you can provide a better answer than the existing answers, just post your own answer to the question.  There is no need, and a fair bit of harm, in posting duplicate questions just so you can post your own answer.

Comment: If the question is good (e.g. not too broad or SuperUser), and you can't answer it in a more concise manner, it's absolutely fine to answer with a guide. You can cite other answers as long as you provide the proper attribution. You may create a community wiki, but that's not required. But note that questions that require a guide to answer often are too broad for SO.

Comment: If, on the other hand, what you want is to gather together the information of several different answers on different questions, to create some sort of step-by-step tutorial... then SO is not the right place for that.

Comment: "if we can create a post, to put together all the answers that might be beneficial to those who have problems related to these kind of equipment/software/configs"  That question would be Too Broad.  SO questions aren't there to answer all possible questions on some broad topic.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Gathering the information of several existing answers in one place wouldn't be proper.

If those answers cover the same subject, by virtue of being different posts can be voted on individually, and so their relative quality and usefulness can be signaled to future readers.

If those answers cover different, although related, subjects; it would be very hard to imagine a good, on-topic, question that could have that would be answered by that single answer. Almost any such a question would be closable as being *too broad*.

While there are some *canonical* questions that work more or less in that way, and are used as dupe-targets for many variations on very typical questions, they are extremely rare, and are usually put together by community consensus in a given tag. It is not an effort **to take on lightly**.

The same thing if you want to build some sort of step-by-step tutorial. Such a post belongs in a blog, or some other kind of site. A question that requires that kind of answer would also be *too broad* and wouldn't fit in Stack Overflow.